# RecyclerView.setAdapter not being resolved

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Everything works as in other projects but for some reason I'm unable to set the projectListItems ( a recycler view ) adapter because it won't resolve setAdapter()...

binding.projectListItems.setAdapter(adapter); in the ProjectsActivity.java

Cleaned and Rebuilt project... also Invalidated cache and restarted.

ProjectsActivity.java

```java
package com.example.poleprofilingapp.ui;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import com.example.poleprofilingapp.R;
import com.example.poleprofilingapp.databinding.ActivityProjectsBinding;
import com.example.poleprofilingapp.project.Project;
import com.example.poleprofilingapp.project.ProjectAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class ProjectsAcitivty extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProjectAdapter adapter;
    private ActivityProjectsBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_projects);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        List <Project> projectsList = new ArrayList<>();

        Project project = new Project();
        project.setName("Project 1");
        project.setAddress("Address 1");
        project.setDescription("Test Project 1");
        project.setType("NOVEC");
        project.setCompanyKey("333555");

        projectsList.add(project);

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,
                R.layout.activity_projects);

        adapter = new ProjectAdapter(projectsList, this);

        binding.projectListItems.setAdapter(adapter); // setAdapter not resoleved


    }
}
```

ProjectAdaptor.java

```java
package com.example.poleprofilingapp.project;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


import com.example.poleprofilingapp.R;
import com.example.poleprofilingapp.databinding.ProjectListItemBinding;

import java.util.List;

public class ProjectAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProjectAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Project> projects;
    private Context context;

    public ProjectAdapter(List<Project> projects, Context context) {
        this.projects = projects;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProjectAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ProjectListItemBinding binding = DataBindingUtil
                .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                R.layout.project_list_item,
                parent,
                false);
        return new ViewHolder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProjectAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Project project = projects.get(position);
        holder.projectListItemBinding.setProject(project);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return projects.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        // Binding Vars
        public ProjectListItemBinding projectListItemBinding;

        // Constructor to do view lookups for each subview
        public ViewHolder(ProjectListItemBinding projectLayoutBinding){
            super(projectLayoutBinding.getRoot());
            projectListItemBinding = projectLayoutBinding;
        }
    }
}
```

Project.java ( data model )

```java
package com.example.poleprofilingapp.project;

public class Project {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String description;
    private String type;
    private String companyKey;

    public Project() {
    }

    public Project(String name, String address, String description, String type, String companyKey) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.description = description;
        this.type = type;
        this.companyKey = companyKey;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getCompanyKey() {
        return companyKey;
    }

    public void setCompanyKey(String companyKey) {
        this.companyKey = companyKey;
    }
}
```

XML - activity_projects.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="project"
            type="com.example.poleprofilingapp.project.Project"/>
    </data>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.ProjectsAcitivty">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/projectListItems"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

projects_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="project"
            type="com.example.poleprofilingapp.project.Project"/>
    </data>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/projectListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        tools:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="@{project.name}"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Test Project"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: You're setting content view *(R.layout.activity_projects)* and then using data binding in the same activity inside **`onCreate()`**, use any one at a time !

Comment: what is that thing binding ?? where is you recycler view ?

Comment: put in xml files.  Followed this at teamtreehouse.com... Works in another package but it is not SDK 29 as this one is.  The course package I used this from is using SDK 27.  Something with a change from android support to androidx I think is causing this somehow... or I am missing something.

Comment: I've located the problem...  in the generated file it is generating an import the the support.v7 library instead of the new androidx.  Have no understanding of how to fix this.  In no way should there be a -1 to this question as the code written to bind is correct but the generated import is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that I migrated the project over to androix but never changed the RecyclerView to support androix method.  So in the build folder my generated binding class was trying to us android.support.v7..... in place of androidx.recyclerview.....

So what fixed this was updating the XML then running Invalidating the Chache / Restart...

Whala all fixed up.

Answer (score 0):

> Inside the onCreate intialize your bindiing variable

```
  ActivityMainBinding mBinding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);


}
```

> In onStart method set you layoutManager and adapter

```
   @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mBinding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    UserAdapter adapter = new UserAdapter(getApplicationContext(),usersList());
    mBinding.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

> and this is list

```
private List<Animals> usersList(){
        List<Animals> animalsList = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] animals = {"Tiger","Monkey","Dog","Lion","Zebra","Horse","Cat"};
        String[] types = {"Carnivore","Herbivore","Omnivore","Carnivore","Herbivore","Herbivore","Omnivore"};
        int[] image = {R.drawable.all_call,R.drawable.done,R.drawable.hide,R.drawable.all_call};

    for (int i=0;i<animals.length;i++){
        Animals users = new Animals(
                animals[i],
                types[i],
                image[i]
        );
        animalsList.add(users);
    }

    return animalsList;
}
```

Comment: I found the issue... posting now.